# How to move a plant aquarium, to another house, city?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants, plants

I have a an aquarium with normal glass, in the next couple of months we move to another city.

### Detail

Size of the aquarium is 90 x 40 x 30 cm, it has so many plants that I use CO<sub>2</sub> capsule and filtration. I have shrimp, fish, snails, and the plants.

The floor is well built-up with aquarium specific soil (around 5cm) and some branch to which I stick some of my specific plants on top of them.

### Questions

How to move it to have minimum loss?

Is it possible to move the aquarium without break the glass, in a acceptance way, or acceptable weight?

### EDIT

Added images:

[image: Aquarium Image]
[image: Sample Aquatic Plant 1]
[image: Sample Aquatic Plant 2]
[image: Sample Aquatic Plant 3]
[image: Sample Aquatic Plant 4]
[image: Sample Aquatic Plant 5]

Comment: Don't worry about the strength of an empty aquarium . I now  have a couple 55's I move around the yard  without problem ( 122 X 30 X 45 mm) .

Comment: Empty... the issue is that it's filled

Comment: You cannot move a filled aquarium, you'll need to drain it. How long is the journey to the new location?

Comment: 400~500KM on car, and 1~2 hour consumed in the traffic of central city

Comment: Full is not a reasonable possibility ; 300 + lb ( 150 kg) plus movement of the water.  I once moved a 55 g ( 200+ L) about 1/3 full with the top sealed with tape ; I would not try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on who will move it . I assume you don't want to disturb the plant roots.  If you are going to put it into a car yourself it should be alright. Put fish and shrimp into a bag or other container. Remove any rocks , wood , or other decorations, remove the water to about 1 cm, lift it carefully by the edges of the bottom ( not the center) and set it somewhere flat .It will still be heavy , about 50 # or about 25 kg. You may be able to leave the branch. Put plastic film over the top to maintain humidity for the plants ; they should be good for a day or two. If it will be moved by others , 
I think you will need to empty it completely. When empty the glass itself is very strong.

Comment: so, but that weight, it won't damage the glass? (it's man made aquarium, not the corner round glass, and i'm worry if the bottom fell off... i think i also need to add image :-s give me time, i'll update and inform you by the night or tomorrow

Comment: Why don't you want to move it by the center? Surely it should be supported all around or the center could droop and the additional strain will crack the bottom?

Comment: I guess I am too old; I have had accidents lifting the center of stainless frame aquariums.

Comment: @Henders i'm not sure what you mean, but it currently is placed on a Styrofoam, and buttom of it is a flat sheet of stone...

Comment: Nice tank; i will stay with my original answer, be sure to remove decorations. I think the broad leaf plant ( bacopa ?) could be thinned for the move.

Comment: @blacksmith37 to be honest i don't know their name :D i shorten them yesterday, but again put them in the soil in multiple hand, so the light would reach the lower part of aquarium... so the answer is as you said... still i'm wonder if i can raise it up, since it got no handle.. and went in a little inside the styrofoam pad